How to make video fullscreen in portrait mode like a youtube short video with chewie in flutter?
I have tried to build an short video player application (like youtube shorts, tiktok etc.) where I have to play short videos from network with .m3u8 format. Thats why I choosed chewie over video_player. But with chewie I am not able to play the video with fullscreen in potrait mode but can be done with video_player. In chewie if I put the aspectratio of my video then also their exist some weired padding(Not fullscreen). Here the problem is with only video_player, we can't play video with .m3u8 extension.
I have fixed the issue by manipulating the chewie library's code. I have changed at player_with_controls.dart file. I have simply commented their code which was causing the issue and used VideoPlayer only.
import 'package:chewie/src/chewie_player.dart';
import 'package:chewie/src/helpers/adaptive_controls.dart';
import 'package:chewie/src/notifiers/index.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:video_player/video_player.dart';

class PlayerWithControls extends StatelessWidget {
  const PlayerWithControls({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final ChewieController chewieController = ChewieController.of(context);

    double calculateAspectRatio(BuildContext context) {
      final size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
      final width = size.width;
      final height = size.height;

      return width > height ? width / height : height / width;
    }

    Widget buildControls(
      BuildContext context,
      ChewieController chewieController,
    ) {
      return chewieController.showControls
          ? chewieController.customControls ?? const AdaptiveControls()
          : const SizedBox();
    }

    Widget buildPlayerWithControls(
      ChewieController chewieController,
      BuildContext context,
    ) {
      return Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          if (chewieController.placeholder != null)
            chewieController.placeholder!,
          InteractiveViewer(
            transformationController: chewieController.transformationController,
            maxScale: chewieController.maxScale,
            panEnabled: chewieController.zoomAndPan,
            scaleEnabled: chewieController.zoomAndPan,
            child: Center(
              child: AspectRatio(
                aspectRatio: chewieController.aspectRatio ??
                    chewieController.videoPlayerController.value.aspectRatio,
                child: VideoPlayer(chewieController.videoPlayerController),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          if (chewieController.overlay != null) chewieController.overlay!,
          if (Theme.of(context).platform != TargetPlatform.iOS)
            Consumer<PlayerNotifier>(
              builder: (
                BuildContext context,
                PlayerNotifier notifier,
                Widget? widget,
              ) =>
                  Visibility(
                visible: !notifier.hideStuff,
                child: AnimatedOpacity(
                  opacity: notifier.hideStuff ? 0.0 : 0.8,
                  duration: const Duration(
                    milliseconds: 250,
                  ),
                  child: const DecoratedBox(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.black54),
                    child: SizedBox.expand(),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          if (!chewieController.isFullScreen)
            buildControls(context, chewieController)
          else
            SafeArea(
              bottom: false,
              child: buildControls(context, chewieController),
            ),
        ],
      );
    }

    // return LayoutBuilder(
    //     builder: (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints constraints) {
    //   return Center(
    //     child: SizedBox(
    //       // height: constraints.maxHeight,
    //       // width: constraints.maxWidth,
    //       child: AspectRatio(
    //         aspectRatio: calculateAspectRatio(context),
    //         child: buildPlayerWithControls(chewieController, context),
    //       ),
    //     ),
    //   );
    // });
    return VideoPlayer(chewieController.videoPlayerController);
  }
}

That actually resolved the issue but changing library directly is not a good practise for production. Is there anything else or any other way to solve this issue?

You can push request to the dependency repo instead about the changes you made @Sitam

You can use the BetterPlayer package for improved performance and seamless video streaming.
Example:
class ShortVideoPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const ShortVideoPage({super.key});

  @override
  ShortVideoPageState createState() => ShortVideoPageState();
}

class ShortVideoPageState extends State<ShortVideoPage> {
  final List<String> videoUrls = [
    "https://test.m3u8",
    "https://test2.m3u8",
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: PageView.builder(
        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
        itemCount: videoUrls.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return VideoPlayerItem(videoUrl: videoUrls[index]);
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
    
class VideoPlayerItem extends StatefulWidget {
  final String videoUrl;

  const VideoPlayerItem({super.key, required this.videoUrl});

  @override
  VideoPlayerItemState createState() => VideoPlayerItemState();
}

class VideoPlayerItemState extends State<VideoPlayerItem> {
  late BetterPlayerController _betterPlayerController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    BetterPlayerConfiguration betterPlayerConfiguration =
    const BetterPlayerConfiguration(
      aspectRatio: 9 / 16,
      autoPlay: true,
      looping: true,
      controlsConfiguration: BetterPlayerControlsConfiguration(
        showControls: false
      ),
      autoDispose: true,
    );

    _betterPlayerController = BetterPlayerController(betterPlayerConfiguration);
    _betterPlayerController.setupDataSource(
      BetterPlayerDataSource(
        BetterPlayerDataSourceType.network,
        widget.videoUrl,
        videoFormat: BetterPlayerVideoFormat.hls, //for added m3u8
        cacheConfiguration: BetterPlayerCacheConfiguration(
          useCache: true,
          maxCacheSize: 100 * 1024 * 1024, // 100 MB cache
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _betterPlayerController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(child: AspectRatio(aspectRatio: 16/9,child: BetterPlayer(controller: _betterPlayerController,),),),
    );
  }
}


Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?
